# Android custom layout

Tags: android, layout

I am developing an android application with very complex design here is how it should look

[image: Layout design]

I want to achieve this star-like design on the lower half of the image. Icons would represent buttons as well.

What I tried before coming here is 
https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout
But that didn't work out so well.

Does anyone had similar experience ?

Comment: are you familiar wuth a base layout class: ViewGroup?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar, however I have to keep responsivnes for all screens

Comment: that's why i'm saying about the custom ViewGroup

Answer (score 1):

Make an image like that as layout background and place buttons with transparent background wherever u want.

Comment: This just might work, and also an easy solution, I'm gonna try it right away!

Comment: UP Vote if this suggestion helped you

Comment: This is an acceptable answer however it is not complete since you will encounter many problems when comes to onClick listeners. Anyway upvoted.

Comment: what problems u r facing with onClick listeners?

Comment: Now the click area is the whole image including transparent area that overlaps with other transparent areas.

Comment: make small size images that matches the icons and place over it. use RelativeLayout to place the buttons correctly. Re-Size the buttons according to the icons in your images.

Comment: Well you can't position them well that way.